# setResult in intent para parent Activity passing

Tags: android

i am not understanding what is going on in this piece of code. Need help please.

```
     Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RSSNewsReaderPBActivity.class);
            // send result code 100 to notify about product update
            setResult(100, i);
            startActivity(i);
```

and why use int value in it what it do.

```
  This is method of the code 

  protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String url = args[0];
        rssFeed = rssParser.getRSSFeed(url);
        Log.d("rssFeed", " " + rssFeed);
        if (rssFeed != null) {
            Log.e("RSS URL",
                    rssFeed.getTitle() + "" + rssFeed.getLink() + ""
                            + rssFeed.getDescription() + ""
                            + rssFeed.getLanguage());
            RSSDatabaseHandler rssDb = new RSSDatabaseHandler(
                    getApplicationContext());
            WebSite site = new WebSite(rssFeed.getTitle(),
                    rssFeed.getLink(), rssFeed.getRSSLink(),
                    rssFeed.getDescription());
            rssDb.addSite(site);
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RSSNewsReaderPBActivity.class);
            // send result code 100 to notify about product update
            setResult(100, i);
            startActivity(i);
            return null;
        } else {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    textViewMessage
                            .setText("Rss url not found. Please check the url or try again");
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: One comment go through the very basics of Android. Read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html AND THIS IS JUST A START.

Comment: i know about intent just not understanding setResult what do in this and why 100 is pass.

Comment: It depends on the developer what result he passes back to the previous activity. Whatever developer passes back he/she will have to handle accordingly.

Comment: i think it moving back to the class which is written in intent.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i edit code from This is method of code

Comment: kindly see my edit code to tell me whats setResult is actually doing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the setResult is wrongly used : setResult must be called before finishing an activity, it will inform the parent activity that your current one has worked well or if it had a problem (considering the parent activity has started the new one with startActivityForResult)

Let's say you have an ActivityOne that will launch an ActivityTwo:

ActivityOne:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

in ActivityTwo at the moment you want to close the activity:

```
if(everything_is_ok)
    setResult(1);
else
    setResult(0);
finish();
```

In ActivityOne, you will get notified that ActivityTwo has been finished:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        if(resultCode == 1)
            //everything went fine
        else
            //something went wrong
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!